# Is there a way to find out of an INSERT/UPDATE command in Cassandra resulted in a new row being created or an old row being updated?

Tags: cassandra

#### Question

Is there a way to find out of an INSERT/UPDATE command in Cassandra resulted in a new row being created or an old row being updated?

#### Background

The reason I am asking is because we would like to maintain a count of the number of rows in the table.

Thanks!

Comment: Maintaining a row count is hard for Cassandra,  because the writers are distributed.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on the problem of counting rows in Cassandra that might help: http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=24

Comment: @Richard good blog post, but a minor correction: I think it's pretty much only MySQL that gives you a fast row count. PostgreSQL has to run a full scan also due to concurrent access issues. What it does give you is the guarantee that you're seeing a consistent view of the data (assuming you want one), due to its ACID properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally you can't do this without giving up a lot of performance, both because you'd cripple the log-structured nature of the storage engine, and because you need to lock to avoid races with other clients.  If you could do it performantly, Cassandra would do it out of the box!

So the "right" solution is to figure out how to live without an exact row count, or to make assumptions based on what your application is doing ("99% of the time, this kind of update is for a new row"), or both.

Answer (score 0):

You could query Cassandra before doing the update/insert. If the query indicates the presence of a row, you know it will be an update rather than an insert.

Comment: If you have multithreaded writers you will need an external locking strategy to make this accurate.  It will also significantly slow down your insert rate.

Answer (score 0):

*Noob speaking*

You could make use of a counter. This works only for a long value and this will increment instead of overwrite the value.